# SharePoint 2016 and OneDrive On-Premise - move files from OneDrive to SharePoint libraries

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive

Background:-
We have got a SharePoint 2016 On-Premise and we have setup MySites (which has OneDrive as a feature).

What are we after:-
Like in Internet Explorer users can open up Windows Explorer via a Library, we are looking at a similar option on MS Edge. Some articles suggest we can achieve it via OneDrive. Can someone throw some light on this as to how we can get a similar functionality?

Please note that most articles refer to Microsoft 365 and we are not yet there.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable and use IE Mode in Microsoft Edge to make the open with explorer works again in SharePoint server 2016, for detailed steps, please refer to this simialr issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/520044/how-will-the-open-with-explorer-function-be-replac.html

Comment: Thank you @Julie_MSFT. Appreciate your response. I think that feature in Edge can address some of the key requirements in our company.